# Android ListView doesn't expand the whole screen?

Tags: android, listview

I've the following Activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FiltersLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/FiltersScroll"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/featureList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="*" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </ExpandableListView>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the `ExpandableListView` to scratch the screen, but it shows as the following:

![Anzroiz ListView][1]

Comment: list view can be scrolled already, why do u want it to be inside a scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the height of the `ScrollView` to `fill_parent`, but really you should omit the `ScrollView` entirely as a `ListView` provides its own scrolling.

Comment: Can you help me on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322100/android-listview-doesnt-expand-the-whole-screen-2 ?