# Android ListView doesn't expand the whole screen

Tags: android, listview

I've problem similar to the one here: [Android ListView doesn't expand the whole screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321607/android-listview-doesnt-expand-the-whole-screen)

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ResultLayout">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ListView"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pagingPanel"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/ManSpinner"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In this case, I should have a `ScrollView` or the `PagingPanel` `LinearLayout` will disappear.

### Edit

The desired layout is to have all the elements stacked on top of each other. but if the elements exceed the page height, a scroll should be added to the `ListView`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Seeing you layout you should only be able to see the spinner right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a vertical `LinearLayout`, You can't have multiple `fill_parent` for `layout_height` of your `LinearLayout` elements. What layout you would like to achieve? Uniformly divide screen for all elements?

Another problem is that using `ListView` in `ScrollView` is not a good idea also because `ListView` itself is scrollable.

You should write what layout you would like to achieve with your XML. Also generally is a good practice to write your XML in multiple steps and iterate to woking solution layout by layout.

**EDIT:** Ok, try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/ResultLayout">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pagingPanel"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/ManSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It worked like a magic.. Many thanks!, BTW, can you provide me with a link to learn me how to layout components together.. I am very new to Android!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Few months ago when I started with android I had read these series of tutorials... and I think they are written very friendly: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/